# .Net Core Logger Configuration

Tags: logging, .net-core

I'm tring to use logger in .Net Application configured from appsettingsjson

This is how my settings for development looks like

[image]

In the Startup class, I'm creating a logger for Console

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(provider => { provider.AddConsole(); });

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();

        logger.LogInformation("Test log");
```

As a result I'm expecting not to see any log, since mininum level for the Console default log is Error.
But, I see the log and don't understand why configuration is not applied.  I've tried even to use filter in LoggerFactory, but result is the same.
No minimal loggin level set in CreateHostBuilder.
Wondering what could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the default logging configuration was not applied for Development. Since I've added Console in development as well is tarted to work.

But, weird, that default settings (for all layout) was not applied